# VB 2012 (Me.Hide does not hide the form)

Tags: vb.net, forms, hide

I have some code which executs on form load, one which is me.hide:

```
FILE_NAME = Replace$(GetCommonFolder() & "\abc", "\\", "\")
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

objWriter.Write("")
objWriter.Close()
Me.hide
```

However when the form launches, it does not hide, it is visible. I also use a context menu strip and a notify icon control.

Comment: try me.Visible=false ..

Comment: Doesn't work either.  The Load event fires *because* code called the Show() method or set Visible = True.  This code simply doesn't belong in a Load event handler, move it to the constructor or another class.

Comment: Try putting the code in the Me.Shown event